# Display file path in textbox in tkinter GUI

Tags: file, user-interface, tkinter, filepath

I got stuck.... 
Please help..

I am trying to display a file path  that was selected in the text box in GUI. I managed to get the ode to display the actual content of the file.

```
    def OnButtonClick1(self):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, tkinter.END)
        filename = askopenfilename()
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for file in f:
            self.entry.insert(0,file)
            print(filename)
```

Please help me with getting it to display file path.
Thanks

EDIT:
           def OnButtonClick1(self):
               self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get())
               self.entry.focus_set()
               self.entry.selection_range(0, tkinter.END)
               filename = askopenfilename()
               with open(filename,'r') as f:
                   for file in f:
                       self.entry.insert(0,filename)
                       print(filename)

Now this prints the filepath but more than one time?? Strange.. Please help :)

EDIT 2:
I found the solution!!!!

```
   with open(filename,'r') as f:
       for file in f:
            data = f.read()
            self.entry.insert(0,filename)
            print(filename)
```

Happy DAYS!!!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have the file path in the variable `filename`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I need the code to display the actual file path in the txtbox. Currently it only displays the content of the file selected in the txtbox

Comment: Well, then do the same with the file path: `self.entry.insert(0, filename)`. The function `askopenfilename` already returns the absolute file path of the selected file.

Comment: Thank you. It works in that now it prints the filepath to the textbox. but it prints it more than once. Why? Please advise. See edited code above